# UTF-8: Russian characters and Euro symbol do not appear and store in mysql table

Tags: php, utf-8

I have to store text written in the Russian language in mySQL table and also I have to pick up the Euro symbol from the mySQL table and present it to the user in the browser. I used the mysql_set_charset('utf8') and it successfully saves the text in Russian in the database, but then the Euro symbol does not appear. If I remove that statement then the Euro symbol appears but the Russian characters are stored incorrectly.

Comment: why don't you store euro as &euro; ?

Comment: I already have a currency table and I just pick up the symbol from that table.

Comment: @Mihai Because there's no need to garble your text if you handle encodings correctly.

Comment: Without more information it's impossible to tell why the € symbol specifically does not work for you, but see [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) for a general rundown of steps.

Comment: is your table (or field) set to urf-8?

Comment: Yes both tables are set to utf-8. means the table which stores the currency symbols and the table in which i store the russian text both are set to utf-8

Answer (score 1):

A table in "utf8_general_ci" can store Russian and Euro without any problems.
http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_general_ci.european.html

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the Euro is not posted on the Webpage. Maybe your html document is not set to UTF-8. UTF-8 lists the euro sign.

Comment: I used the following meta tag on that page but didnt work
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >

Comment: You should probably expand more on what you mean, Daniel. There are several forms of encodings. The meta encoding is what the response is telling the client the charset is. This can be achieved by using the meta tag in your html head, or you could use a php `header('Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf8');` But the document in itself also has an encoding. Make sure that the document is encoded as UTF-8, not only telling the client that it is.