# UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 Confusion

Tags: php, utf-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UTF-8: Russian characters and Euro symbol do not appear and store in mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280745/utf-8-russian-characters-and-euro-symbol-do-not-appear-and-store-in-mysql-table)

I have a mysql table to store currency information including their symbols. The column that stores the symbol is of collation 'utf8_general_ci. The charset of the web page is set to UTF-8.
But when I fetch the Euro and Pound symbol from that table it is not shown correctly on the browser. If I change the page charset to ISO-8859-1 those symbols appear. I need the UTF-8 because I have some russian characters as well which ISO-8859-1 does not support.

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) - The typical guess: the *database connection encoding*

Comment: I already used this
mysql_select_db($ms_dbName, $pr_mysql);
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');

Comment: You've already asked this question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/12280745/469210

Comment: @user Then try to follow the complete example in the article and figure out where you deviate from it. You have probably already inserted garbage data into the database which you now cannot fix. That cannot be the measure for the correctness of your app. You need to get it right from zero first.

Answer (score 1):

- Your entire database should be utf8;
- Your tables should be utf8;
- Your columns should be utf8;
- [Your connection should be in utf8;](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-syntax.html)
- Your http response should be in utf8;
- Your file should be saved as utf8;
- Your content-type should be set to utf8;
- Your metatag should be set to utf8.

Comment: explain this point 
Your http response should be in utf8;

Comment: Add this to the top of your php script:
`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your connection is using the correct encoding. Execute `SET NAMES 'UTF8'` before you run any select queries.

Comment: I tried the following three statements but of no avail.
1. ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
2. mysql_query( "set names 'utf8'" ) ;
3. mysql_set_charset('utf8');